# Primefaces p:blockUI not blocking modal p:dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Problem: I have a `p:dialog` on my web application that is opened when the user selects a dataTable row. This Dialog contains a `p:lineChart` and i have two more buttons that define the X Axis intervals of this same. These buttons call a method that makes a new search at my database and generates a new CartesianChartModel to be shown in that `p:lineChart`.

I tried to use a `p:blockUI` to block my screen whenever the user click on those buttons, but the only thing that is being blocked  is the content behind that Modal `p:dialog`. Even setting the `p:blockUI` to block a div that wraps all my page content does'nt work.

When i set my `p:dialog` parameter `modal` to `false`, everything goes fine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Problem solved. I've set the buttons to close the dialog, show the "Loading..." blockUI then reopen the dialog with the new lineChart generated.